# Declaring an array at a specific memory address in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips, qtspim

How can I declare an array at memory location 100(Decimal) in a MIPS program?

Comment: That probably depends on the particular compiler / assembler / interpreter you are using. Which is it?

Comment: @MartinVidner I am using QtSpim v9.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `spim` simulator supports the optional `data` directive argument as detailed [here](http://students.cs.tamu.edu/tanzir/csce350/reference/assembler_dir.html).

> `.data <addr>`
>
> The following data items should be stored in the data segment. If the optional argument  `addr` is present, the items are stored beginning at address `addr`.

Therefore, using `spim`, you can store any data at an exact address as long as it is within the range of the user data segment. In `spim`, the reserved range is `0x10000000 - 0x10040000`.

So,  for example, if you wanted to store an array at address `0x10000030` you would write:

```
.data 0x10000030
list: .word 3, 0, 1, 2, 6, -2, 4, 9, 3, 7
```

However, address `100` is not within the acceptable range for the `spim` simulator's user data segment (or probably in any other circumstance since it would be part of the first page of memory).

I tried a `.data 100` directive in `spim`, just to see what it would do when I tried to load from it, and the answer is a `Memory address out of bounds` error.